# Control 5V supplied seven segment led group with 3.3V PIC microcontroller

Tags: led

Although the microcontroller voltage required to control the LEDs is 3.3V, the LEDs were connected to 5V for more brightness. The Q9 transistor stays always ON, even if HIGH or LOW is coming from PIC. In this state, i can't control the LED. I have no chance to supply the PIC on the PCB with 5V right now. How can I control the transistor by adding the least components or changing the component values only?
[image]

**EDIT**
I'm redesigning the board while trying the suggested methods. The starting point of this problem was to connect the LEDs to 5V to increase the brightness of the LEDs.

1. If I connected to 3.3V and changed the value of the R2 resistor, wouldn't I still get the brightness?
2. Also in the current circuit, when PIC pin1 is LOW, 87mA current flows through the LED. Isn't there a problem here too?

Note: Please warn me if it is wrong to write here instead of a second question.

Comment: Use an npn level shifter (open collector with pull up to higher voltage) on upper transistor

Comment: Why do you need PCIpin1 and Q9 at all? Connect R2 direct to 5V and it should work with just PICpin2 and Q8.

Comment: Actually this led is a part of seven segment display. There're 3 character on display. Q8 select which character to be active. The pin controls the Q9 also controls other led on other character. Thus this provide less microcontroller pin usage actually.

Comment: Which PIC microcontroller? Does it have 5V tolerant IO pins?

Comment: For 7-seg display multiplex driving, I'd use high-side source drivers like TD62783 for loading character data *(I know, 62783 is obsolete. Just gave an example to show the concept idea)*. Then you can turn the character on via a low-side switch (BJT or NMOS). More practical, and cost- & space-efficient.

Comment: RD62783 similar ICs could be regular and clean as you said. Is it possible turn-on and turn-off 5V rail connected leds with a 3.3V uC?

Comment: Of course it is. The IC has a VS pin, it is the supply for load side. The IC accepts inputs as low as 2V.

Answer (score 3):

To block current through Q1, at least emitter voltage should be on it's base. To provide that, R5 is used as pull-up. R4 will drop voltage on Q1 base when Q3 starts to conduct, thus closing Q1. It's not cheapest solution, but easy to build using off-the-shelf components. R4 can be smaller, when more Q1 collector current is nedded. See:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDJVOv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT**
**This doesn't meet requirements - lowers voltage to 3v3**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuZ7J6.png)</sup>

Comment: The proposed circuit by you is good, i simulate it. But it can be applicable in the next pcb version. I need a patched and i do it with less component changing. Do you mean the circuit proposed here with NPN transistor in your other comment?

Comment: This is this level shifter, I'm thinking how to do it other way. Does Your Pic (no exact number provided) have open-collector I'os - Maybe they can tolarate 5V (check documentation) - then only one extra resistor would be nedded

Comment: The PIC is 18f45k22. I checked it, but there's no open collecter Output as i know. Only I2C pins have open-drain.

Comment: What led are You using, check last edit in answer

Comment: @fifi_22 The whole point of using 5V for the LED's was for increased brightness, according to the OP. The emitter follower will limit voltage to 3.3V - Vbe. In that case you could just stick with the PNP and use 3.3V in stead of 5V.

Answer (score 2):

One approach that could be used with the existing PCB is to put a capacitor across R3.

The capacitor will charge up to ~4.3V when PIC pin 1 is low (5V - Vbe) so that when the PIC pin 1 goes high the transistor B-E junction go up to about 7.5V and turn the transistor off.

The capacitor value should be such that the time constant of R3 and the capacitor is longer than the multiplexer frequency.

During the on-time the capacitor will charge to about 4.3v (5V - Vbe). During the off-time the capacitor must not discharge to less than ~1V or the transistor will start to turn on, even though PicPin1 is still at 3.3v. In one time constant it will charge down to about 1.5V so the time constant must be equal or greater than the off-time.

If this is a surface mount board it is often easy to put a capacitor of the same size directly across an existing resistor just by mounting it on top.

[image]

Comment: That's smart! But has one issue (same as driving mosfet in bootstrap) it works as long, as signal changes - not possible to use in just hi-side switching with unlimited on-time. Quite application specific, but smart.

Comment: How to select the value of capacitor? It's a SMD board yes. If it works, it is easy to apply.

Comment: It also isn't ideal to apply a voltage higher than Vcc to a uC.

Comment: @fifi_22 - no argument there - I wouldn't do it except as a hack to make an incorrectly designed PCB function. If the multiplexing needs to be stopped (eg to turn off the display) it can be done by turning off the low side drive.

Comment: @SimSon - again, no argument but the current is limited to a few hundred microamps by R3 and if the GPIO pin just goes between logic low and logic high (not high-z) then the upper FET in the output will take the current going only  few millivolts above the positive rail - the ESD diodes won't conduct at all (except maybe at startup).

Comment: @BerkerIşık - as I mention in the answer, the time constant needs to be longer than the multiplexing frequency. I edited the answer with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to just put a resistor across the Base and Emitter of the PNP transistor. This makes a voltage divider with R3, dropping the Base-Emitter voltage low enough to turn the transistor off when the MCU is putting out 3.3V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvCrh9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However this resistor also bypasses some of the current going into the Base, so its value must be carefully chosen to make the transistor switch fully on and off. With R4 = 1.5 KΩ the 'on' Base current drops from ~900 μA to ~400 μA. With a larger value the Base current is higher, but the 'off' Base-Emitter voltage may not be low enough to turn the transistor fully off.

This problem can be solved by reducing R3's resistance to provide more current. With R3 = 2.2 kΩ and R4 = 760 Ω the Base current is restored to ~900 μA.

However this exacerbates another problem - current is injected into the MCU's output when it is high. With 2.2 kΩ and 760 Ω the injected current is about 2 mA, so a 7 segment display could inject up to 14 mA into the MCU. If it draws less than this normally then the injected current may cause its supply voltage to rise above 3.3 V, possibly causing it to misoperate or even blow up!

So you really need a level shifting circuit that doesn't inject current into the MCU. Here's the simplest way to do it:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftQP0L.png)</sup>

An NPN transistor is inserted in series with R3, with its Base connected to the MCU's 3.3 V supply. In this [Common Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_base) configuration it acts as a controlled current source. The Collector current is almost the same as the Emitter current (only reduced by the tiny Base current required to produce it), but the Collector *voltage* will 'float' up to the PNP transistor's Base. When the MCU output is high the NPN transistor's Base-Emitter junction is shorted out by R3, so it turns fully off and delivers virtually no current to the PNP transistor, ensuring that it is also turned fully off. The Emitter cannot go above 3.3V so no current is injected into the MCU output.

This configuration also maintains the 'polarity' of the control signal, so you don't need to change any program code. I changed R3 to 3.3 kΩ to maintain close to 900 μA, but the original 4.7 kΩ (which produces ~600 μA in this circuit) might still work.